# Bootstrap3 set only the width of input text in input-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap3 I would like to set the width of the input type="text" in the input-Group.

I found these two solutions, but in this way I set the total width of all elements and not only the input text width.

```css
.paginator {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="paginator">
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <div class="input-group-btn input-group-sm">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> &lt;&lt; </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> &lt; </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Pag</button>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-btn input-group-sm">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">of 44</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> &gt; </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> &gt;&gt; </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
          <div class="input-group-btn input-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> &lt;&lt; </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> &lt; </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Pag</button>
          </div>
          <input class="form-control" type="text">
          <div class="input-group-btn input-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">of 44</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> &gt; </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> &gt;&gt; </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/2X2ZBStbxP)

How do I set only the width of the text input with bootstrap?
Thank you

-- EDIT --

I tried to set an inline class for text input as suggested, but this is the result.

[bootply edit](http://www.bootply.com/GssZuMoEs6)

Nobody can help me?
Thanks